# pass var to IEnumerable view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(User user)
    {
        var users = new User(user);
        Context.Users.Insert(user);
        return RedirectToAction("RegisterdUsers");
    }

    public ActionResult RegisterdUsers()
    {
        var users = Context.Users.FindAll();
        return View(users); 
    }
```

And here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsFantasy_2._0.Models.User>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "RegisterdUsers";
}

<h2>RegisterdUsers</h2>
<table>  
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.username)
    </th>
</tr>
```

So as you can see i send users to my view and i want to use IEnumerable to iterate through users. But when i try to use the model m=> m.username it cant find username?
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`m` represents your `Model`. And your model is `IEnumerable<SportsFantasy_2._0.Models.User>` which doesn't have a `username` property.Use a loop if you want to display all users.

Comment: The pluralsight tutorial im looking at he does this and finds everything in his model somehow

Comment: Selman22 is right. You must have missed something in the tutorial. Check if there isn't a foreach, or perhaps the call to DisplayNameFor(...) is inside a display template or an editor template.

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate as it is IEnumerable of some type not a simple type:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.username)
    </th>
}
```

Comment: Im watching a tutorial on pluralsight and they don't do the foreach loop there. Anyway i tried the foreach but when i try to build  @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.UserName) i get this error "Error 2 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:" and then it shows a lot of extensions

Comment: IEnumerable is used when there will be multiple object if single object is expected then it should be simple Model

Comment: So if i send one object with multiple objects in it i should not use IEnumerable?

Comment: yes then your inner object will be iEnumerable but View Binding Model will be single  object

Comment: But in the tutorial im following they use IEnumerable. How do i use it if i want to use it? Lets say that i have multiple objects. In that case what am i doing wrong?

Comment: then just iterate the way i mentioned

Comment: you can use List as well

Comment: If i try your solution i get this error: "Anyway i tried the foreach but when i try to build @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.UserName) i get this error "Error 2 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:" and then it shows a lot of extensions –"